# Indesign JavaScript Loop with findGrep

Tags: javascript, grep, adobe-indesign

I'm tryin to combine an existing script I have which cuts the selected text and pastes it in a new anchored frame next to the main text frame with a GREP Find/Replace Query I have to select the respective text.
(Every text framed by two ##before and after## should be placed in a separate anchored textframe. The # should be removed and the text should not be left in the previous textframe. (cut/paste instead of copy/paste) Its for marginalia next to the main text.)

I nearly got it to work but I get error messages because of the repeating

> var mySelection=app.activeDocument.findGrep ()[0];

at the end of the "for loop" which I have to put in so that it repeats the query.

I tried with changing the counter a bit but the script below actually is what works best so far. But I of course get an error message because it's not really counting up.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? I am an absolute beginner with scripting and I am at my wits end.

```js
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing; 
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat="##(.+?)##( ?)";
    app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo="$1";
    
    var mySelection = app.activeDocument.findGrep ()[0];

    var theOStyles = app.activeDocument.objectStyles.everyItem().name;   
    var myOStyleName = myDisplayDialog();   
    var myOStyle = app.activeDocument.objectStyles.item(myOStyleName); 
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < mySelection.length; i++) {
      
    var myBounds = [ "0mm", "0mm", "30mm", "20mm"];
    mySelection.changeGrep();
    var myContent = mySelection.contents;
    
    var myFrame = mySelection.insertionPoints[0].textFrames.add(); // should this be [i]?
    myFrame.parent.parentTextFrames[0].characters.length;   // should this be [i]?
    myFrame.geometricBounds = myBounds;   
    myFrame.applyObjectStyle(myOStyle,  true);    
    myFrame.contents = myContent; //
    
    myFrame.fit (FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
    mySelection.contents = "";
    
    var mySelection=app.activeDocument.findGrep ()[0];  // this is probably what is wrong. Tried i+1 here
    }
       
    function myDisplayDialog()    
    {    
        var myFieldWidth = 150;    
        var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({name:"Objektstil für verankerten Rahmen"});    
        with(myDialog.dialogColumns.add())    
        {    
            with(dialogRows.add())    
            {    
                with(dialogColumns.add())    
                {    
                    staticTexts.add({staticLabel:"Objektstil:",     minWidth:myFieldWidth});    
                }    
                with(dialogColumns.add())    
                {    
                    var myOStyleDropDown = dropdowns.add({stringList:theOStyles,     selectedIndex:theOStyles.length-1});    
                }    
            }    
        }    
        var myResult = myDialog.show();    
        if(myResult == true)    
        {    
            var aOStyle = theOStyles[myOStyleDropDown.selectedIndex]    
            myDialog.destroy();    
        }    
        else    
        {    
            myDialog.destroy();    
            exit();    
        }    
        return aOStyle ;    
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It's: Exception has occurred.
Error Code# 21: undefined is not an object @ file 
at the "for" string

Comment: Did you try my solution? Let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry, it showed as deleted when I wanted to comment. Now it's here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised if you managed nearly got it to work, since I didn't.

So I just rewrote the main part and now it works more or less:

```
// find all the patterns in the document
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "##(.+?)##( ?)";
var finds = app.activeDocument.findGrep();
if (finds.length == 0) { alert('Nothing was found'); exit()}

var obj_style = myDisplayDialog();

/* wrong solution ----------------------------------------------------
// loop through all the results and insert anchored frames
// for (var i=0; i<finds.length; i++) {
//    var anchored_frame = finds[i].insertionPoints[i].textFrames.add();
//    anchored_frame.contents = finds[i].contents.replace(/##/g, '');
//    anchored_frame.applyObjectStyle(obj_style, true);
//    anchored_frame.geometricBounds = ["0mm", "0mm", "30mm", "20mm"];
//    // anchored_frame.fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT); // it doesn't // make much sense if you're defining 'geometricBounds'
// }
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

// loop through all the results and insert anchored frames
var i = finds.length;
while (i--) {
    var ip = finds[i].insertionPoints[0].index;
    var anchored_frame = finds[i].parentStory.insertionPoints[ip].textFrames.add();
    anchored_frame.contents = finds[i].contents.replace(/##/g, '');
    anchored_frame.applyObjectStyle(obj_style, true);
    anchored_frame.geometricBounds = ["0mm", "0mm", "15mm", "30mm"];
}

// find and remove all '##' from the document
// app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "##";
// app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "";
// app.activeDocument.changeGrep();

// find and remove all '#...#' from the document
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "##(.+?)##( ?)";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "";
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();


// no changes below, except two new lines
// --------------------------------------

function myDisplayDialog() {
    var myFieldWidth = 150;
    var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({
        name: "Objektstil für verankerten Rahmen"
    });
    var theOStyles = app.activeDocument.objectStyles.everyItem().name; // the new line
    with(myDialog.dialogColumns.add()) {
        with(dialogRows.add()) {
            with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                staticTexts.add({
                    staticLabel: "Objektstil:",
                    minWidth: myFieldWidth
                });
            }
            with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                var myOStyleDropDown = dropdowns.add({
                    stringList: theOStyles,
                    selectedIndex: theOStyles.length - 1
                });
            }
        }
    }
    var myResult = myDialog.show();
    if (myResult == true) {
        var aOStyle = theOStyles[myOStyleDropDown.selectedIndex]
        myDialog.destroy();
    } else {
        myDialog.destroy();
        exit();
    }
    return app.activeDocument.objectStyles.item(aOStyle); // the new line
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works mostly but It doesn't delete the text in the main text. I tried putting 'finds.contents = "";'  in the loop as it worked in my script but it won't work. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You can delete the ##marked text## with `changeGrep()` after the loop. I've added the lines in my code.

Comment: Ah right. That works. Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Hmm I have to revoke the answer checkmark. I now was able to try it with a bigger document and it works until it doesn't. For some reason, the loop stops working after looping a few times. I get an error-Message at var anchored_frame = finds[i].insertionPoints[i].textFrames.add(); (Object is invalid). In the big document it made around 50 or so marginalia. I tried it with a sample document with 80 occurences in 80 lines and there it stopped after 15 loops.

Comment: Yepp ) The insertion points are tricky beasts. I think I've fixed them now. Only thing -- the loop now inserts the anchor frames in backward mode: from the end to the start. Probably it can be done in normal forward way as well. I can try to figure out if it's matter.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I don't believe the order matters here. I tested it on various cases and I couldn't find a problem with it. Could you maybe explain to me what you did here and why the first didn't work?

Comment: The errors was because the Insertion points. IP basically just an index of the letter in the some text. You do search and get all the findings. Finds[0] starts at, say, 10 and has length, for example 15, so it ends at 25. Finds[0] starts at 30, has some length, etc. IPs of Finds[0] has indexes from 0 to 14 (length). Simplest way to insert something at the start of Finds[0] is to use Finds[0].insetrionPoints[0]. To insert at the start of Finds[1] -- Finds[1].insertionPoints[0], etc. But, it's turned out, as soon as you inserted something in the text the old insert points will shifted forward...

Comment: So if you insert anchored frame it will add +1 to insert points. To insert something at the start Finds[1] you need do Finds[1].insertPoints[1], then Finds[2].insertPoints[2], etc. Increase +1 every time. At some point the index become greater than the length of a Finds[x]. It's impossible, so you get the error. So you need to use the insertPoints of the parentStory instead. And to recalculate the shifts every time. It's possible, but if you do inserting backward you don't need to recalculate the shifts of insert points. Sorry for my English )

Comment: Moreover, I suspect now, I could not change the loop actually. Probably it would be enough just run the loop backward `for (var  i=finds.length-1; i>0; i--)`. Funny.

Comment: Thank you. I still have to learn a lot. I just tried the last thing you wrote with the old solution but it doesn't work. But since the other thing works just fine it doesn't matter much. What I forgot. The only thing I had to change from your script were the geometricBounds since you changed them for some reason. But even I could manage that myself :D Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good luck. I just tired the old variant of the code with backward loop -- it works fine if you change `insertionPoints[i]` to `insertionPoints[0]`. And there should be `i>=0` here: `for (var i=finds.length-1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: Ah yes, now that works too.

Comment: I just noticed that the old variant even works better than the other one. I used the finalized version for a new project but it got stuck at occurences in a table and put these at the top of the document and then proceded anchoring the following occurences at wrong points in the documents. I tried the corrected version of the old varant and this seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Well. Let me know if you need help. I've tested it on a random simply layout. In the real life it may require some tweaks.